# Set SVG height and width to that of the <text> node inside it

Tags: html, css, svg, height, inline

Is there a way to make the width and height of an SVG element equal to the width of the text inside a `text` node inside it?

Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/LEyePy

Here's the SVG markup:

```
<span>I want </span>

<svg width="100%" height="80px">
  <text x="0" y="0" fill="white">
    THESE WORDS
  </text>
</svg>

<span>to be an SVG</span>
```

Ideally, I want the SVG to be treated as an inline element (such as a `span` node).

I want it to render like this:

```
I want THESE WORDS to be an SVG
```

Where `THESE WORDS` are an SVG.

If I do `width="auto" height="auto"`, on the `svg` node, it doesn't render at all.

How do I make an SVG element automatically fit the width of the text element inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any SVG+CSS solution.

You could use some JavaScript to adjust the size:

```
// get the bounding box for the text element
var bbox = text.getBBox();

// set the svg width/height accordingly
svg.setAttribute( 'width', bbox.width );
svg.setAttribute( 'height', bbox.height );

// set the viewbox accordingly
svg.setAttribute( 'viewBox', bbox.x + ' ' + bbox.y + ' ' + bbox.width + ' ' + bbox.height );
```

[**Modified Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYbyvr)

- [`getBBox()` in the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable)

Your general problem is, that an SVG element has no size in the sense like other images. Your canvas is (in theory) of unlimited size.
So in order to determine the size, the browser would have to use all contained elements, render them, grab the rendered coordinates and calculate a maximum bounding box. Afaik no browser does that.

Comment: How about if I want the SVG `text` to wrap to a new line, as if it were a normal text node: http://codepen.io/Tiger0915/pen/zxwpqK

Comment: SVG itself has no means for text wrapping. If you need wrapping, use a `<foreignObject>` to embed HTML (and it wrapping capabilities) into SVG. You won't be able to mimic all inline element properties with a single SVG element.

Comment: Even with `<foreignObject>` you would just have wrapping inside the SVG, but not wrapping of the SVG element itself!